# How to solve this system in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

I want to solve this system in mathematica and i have applied various functions such as Solve, NSolve, etc. but none of them worked. could you help me how could i find my answer?

Comment: You have one equation and 8 unknowns.  What exactly are you expecting `Solve` to do?  Also there are several issues with how you entered your equation. Have a read of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393).

Comment: `Solve` will take everything else as parameters,so thats ok.  The trouble is this expression simlly has no general analytic solutions.